# Angular: ng-repeat not working properly, objects show in console though

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

confused on why my ng-repeat not showing my content. Below is my code for my app.js, client controller, factory, and server controller.
Basically everything does show. All the console logs I wrote do show in the console on chrome and in my terminal, but for some reason the ng-repeat just does not work. 
Sorry in advance for the long question.

```
App routes *************************************
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(
  function($q, $location) {
  return {
      'responseError':function(rejection){
      if (rejection.status == 401){
          $location.url('/');
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
  }
};
});
  $routeProvider
.when('/list',{
  templateUrl: 'assets/partials/list.html',
  controller: 'poemController',
  controllerAs: "meep"
})
 .otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/'
 });
});
```

Here is the HTML. Not sure if it's because of the "controller as" making it difficult or my syntax to grab it is wrong...

```
<h3>Top Shared Poems</h3>
  <center><table>
  <thead>
   <th>
     Title
   </th>
   <th>
     Shared
   </th>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat='tops in meep.newpoem'>
      <td>{{meep.tops.title}}</td>
      <td>{{meep.tops.shared}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table></center>
```

This is my client controller, for some reason this part console logs the newpoem on the console but my ng-repeat still does not work.

```
myApp.controller('poemController', ['poemFactory', '$location', '$routeParams', poemController]);

function poemController(poemFactory, $location, $routeParams){
  var _this = this;
  var shownewpoem = function(){
  console.log('in shownewpoem')
  poemFactory.shownew(function(data){
    console.log('in the shownew controller function')
    this.newpoem=data;
    console.log(this.newpoem)
    console.log('getting the newpoems')
  })
}
shownewpoem();
```

this is my factory side

```
myApp.factory('poemFactory', ['$http', function($http){
var factory = {}

factory.shownew = function(callback){
  $http.get('/shownewpoem').then(function(returned_data){
    console.log(returned_data.data);
    console.log('in the shownew factory')
    callback(returned_data.data);
  })
}
return factory;
}]);
```

this is my serverside controller

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var newPoem = mongoose.model('savedPoem')

this.shownew = function(req,res) {
  newPoem.find({}, function(err,newpoems) {
    console.log('in the server shownew')
    if(err) {
      console.log('did not get newpoem')
    } else {
      console.log('it is going back to factory shownew')
      console.log(newpoems)
      res.json(newpoems);
  }
  })
}

};
```

Thank you!

Comment: using callbacks in `$http` is an anti pattern...use the `$http` promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `_this` which refers to controller instance.

```
_this.newpoem=data;
```

instead of

```
this.newpoem=data;
```

Additinally, use correct variable in `ngRepeat` directive

```
<tr ng-repeat='tops in meep.newpoem'>
      <td>{{tops.title}}</td>
      <td>{{tops.shared}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Works! Thanks! works perfectly, should have known to use _this instead of this. Thanks again!